# Arduino application: else without if but has a if

Tags: arduino

i have some code here, says i have an else without an previous if, the thing is there is a if.
And also HOW do i use modulo in here, says invalid binary operator???

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
}

void loop() {
  delay(500);
  int sensorval = analogRead(A0);
  float outval = (sensorval/1024.0) * 5.0;
  float cel =(outval - .5) * 100;
  float far = (cel*1.8000000)+32;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Farien ");
  lcd.print(far,6);

  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  double secs = (millis()/1000);

  if(secs <= 60.0);
  {
      lcd.print(millis()/1000);
  }
  else
  {
    double hrs = (millis()/1000) / 3600.0;
    double mins = hrs / 60.0;
    double secs = mins % 60;
  }
}
```

THis seems simple enough but i am a rookie and need some major help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if code

```
  if(secs <= 60.0);
```

has a redundant semicolon which terminates the statement. Thus the following block is an unconditional block and consequently the else statement leads to an error.

With regard to the modulo operation: the compiler does not state "invalid operator". It states "invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary operator%". This inplies that you shall not mix doubles and int for this. I would suggest to move away from double and witch completely to integers (e.g. uint32_t).

Comment: yea there is another way you can mix double and int which is using fmod(number1,number2);

Comment: fmiod is not the same operator. It is a function that consumes two doubles. Since integer can be converted (implicitly) by the compiler this works.